# Single powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can i combine below 3 powershell scripts into one single script?

1. Delete user
2. Hide from email address enable in exchange
3. ActiveSync disable
4. Export the result in csv

.

```
Get-content C:\TEMP\Users1.txt |get-aduser |set-aduser -enabled $false
Get-content C:\TEMP\user1.txt | Set-Mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
Get-content C:\temp\users1.txt | set-CASMailbox -ActiveSyncEnabled:$False
Export-Csv "DisableU-$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd_HHmm).csv" -NoType
```

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just put them into any **.ps1* file and run from console by providing the full path to the script.
If you are in the script directory just run:

```
./Script.ps1
```

You might also need to set proper *Execution Policy*. This is the separated topic but just for now you can set it to *unrestricted*.

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

But please read about *Execution Policies*.

Comment: is this how the code will be? Sorry im new for powershell

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`
`Get-content C:\TEMP\Users1.txt |get-aduser |set-aduser -enabled $false`
`Get-content C:\TEMP\user1.txt | Set-Mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true`
`Get-content C:\temp\users1.txt | set-CASMailbox -ActiveSyncEnabled:$False`
`Export-Csv "DisableU-$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd_HHmm).csv" -NoType`

Comment: Put your code (those four lines from your question) inside Script.ps1 file, then set execution policy and after that run the file as I shown.

Comment: HI gabr,

The script run if i use disable.ps1 but there is no csv file created.
got error as below.

cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

Any idea?

Comment: You're not telling Export-Csv what you want it to export.  Are you trying to make a log file?

Comment: Hi Nate, Yes im trying to make log file as well.